# Comment shortcut Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm searching for useful Android Studio keyboard shortcut for commenting code, as in Sublime Text or Eclipse.

When I press either <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>maj</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> nothing happens...

Comment: Are you using an english keyboard layout? I am using a german layout where there is no `/` (there it is `Shift + 7`), so I remapped it to `cmd + 7` as well as `cmd + numpad /` which is working fine for me.

Comment: `cmd + numpad /` is doing it. German keyboard. Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 311, accepted):

## Mac With Numeric pad

**Line Comment** hold both: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

**Block Comment** hold all three:  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

## Mac

**Line Comment** hold both: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+ =</kbd>

**Block Comment** hold all three:  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+ =</kbd>

---

## Windows/linux :

**Line Comment** hold both: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

**Block Comment** hold all three: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Same way to remove the comment block.

---

**To Provide Method Documentation comment** *type `/**` and press Enter* just above  the method name (

It will create a block comment with parameter list and return type like this

```
/**
 * @param userId 
 * @return
 */
public int getSubPlayerCountForUser(String userId){}
```

Comment: If you use the "/" from the numeric pad (if you have one), on the right of the keyboard, you don't have to edit the macro. Seems that "/" on the numeric pad, and "/" in the middle of the keyboard are not the "same" key. (PC/French)

Comment: In my experience you should stick to using the line comment instead of the block comment, as removing the block comment modifies the documentation /** */

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, but it still disrupts it. Try it for yourself; select some block of code with documentation, and press `Ctrl + Shift + /` twice

Comment: I'm on Mac with Android Studio 4.2.1 with a danish keyboard and no numeric keyboard. When I press the combo `cmd` + `+=`, then nothing happens. I have tried the other answers here and also no luck with these.

Comment: does not work on Windows

Answer (score 54):

In spanish keyboard without changing anything I can make a comment with the keys:

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

OR

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

This works because in english keyboard / is located at the same place than - on a spanish keyboard

Comment: For some reason it stopped working for me. Now this combo just folds the block of code. Any clue?

Comment: Yeah the second one just folds every possible block of code in the file, don't use it

Comment: Doesn't work; it collapses, it doesn't comment

Answer (score 26):

Be sure you use the slash (/) on right side of keyboard.

For Line Comment:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

For Block Comment:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

You can see all keymap in Android Studio: `Help ➤ Default Keymap Reference`

Answer (score 22):

On Mac and Turkish Keyboard it is (both for commenting out and uncommenting)

line comment:
<kbd>cmd</kbd> +<kbd>.</kbd>

block comment:
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: cmd + . shrinks method if you are inside a method otherwise it does not work. cmd + alt + . displays green dialog box that's written "There are no custom foldings in the current file" Doesn't these shortcuts work now in AS 3.1? I'm using MacBook Air 2017.

Comment: @Thracian doesnt work on 3.1+, also there are some other bugs like you cant type @ in turkish keyboard

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu i assigned my own shortcuts. It was quite annoying to manually comment or block-comment every often. I use AS 31.3, i can type @ with alt+q, what's not working with yours?

Answer (score 22):

An Example for a **Mac OS X 10.5+** with a **German layout** keyboard **without NumPads**:

1. Open Preferences
2. Search for "Keymap"
3. Expand "Main menu"
4. Expand "Code"
5. Delete all shortcuts (just a suggestion)
6. Add a shortcut for a single line comment (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>)
7. Add a shortcut for a block comment (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>)
8. This way you can be sure that those keys are not mapped (except if you assigned them before to another function)

   [image]

Answer (score 18):

### Reviewing and Changing Keyboard Shortcuts in Android Studio

Keyboard shortcuts can be configured (and reviewed) via the Settings dialog, accessible via `File -> Settings`.

Once this dialog appears, to review (and/or add) a shortcut, do the following:

[image: Modify shortcut dialog]

1. Select *Keymap* in the list on the left. Note that there is a "Keymaps" option, and depending on the original selection, shortcuts assigned to a given feature differ based on the Keymap.
2. Type "comment" or text corresponding to the feature for which the keyboard shortcut is to be reviewed/assigned. Each match has a line entry in the list below, and keyboard shortcuts are shown right-justified along with the feature. For example, both <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SLASH</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> are the two assignments for creating a line comment.

To modify a shortcut:

3. Select the resultant line corresponding to the feature for which the keyboard shortcut is to be reviewed/assigned
4. Right-click, and select the desired Add or Remove option.

Answer (score 13):

In Android studio <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for windows.

Answer (score 13):

for **German Layout** (Deutsches Layout) the default is:

for line Comment:
<kbd>strg</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad(/)</kbd>

for block Comment:
<kbd>strg</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad(/)</kbd>

Answer (score 12):

**Comment method like pro developers:**

Windows/linux:

> Line Comment  : `Ctrl + /`
>
> Block Comment : `Ctrl + Shift`

Method Commenting:

> ```
> Type `/**` and press `Enter Key`
> ```

it will add the comment snippet like we see in standard documentation, give it a try this once.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param addOpacity
 */
public void setOpacityOnUserImage(boolean addOpacity) {
// Your business logic. 
}
```

Comment: Please upvote if you enjoyed using  method commenting shortcut.

Comment: Congratulation for 1500 reputation..!

Answer (score 11):

I use this sequence (not a 'linear' shortcut but useful anyway):

- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (holding <kbd>alt</kbd>) for block comment
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (holding <kbd>alt</kbd>) for line comment

(they use the android studio menu)

Answer (score 8):

On PC it's by default set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. This will toggle commenting a selection or current line.

Answer (score 6):

I am working with a german keyboard and the slash (/) is on the 7 key, meaning access would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>. However, this does not work as this is predefined as something with bookmark 7.

I went to settings (search for keymap) and deleted all existing shortcuts. I than added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>, confirmed deletion of bookmark shortcut and now can work well.

Answer (score 6):

For Line Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

For Block Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

> For multiline comment in android studio
>
> select the statement that you want to commented then
>
> **use ctrl+shift+/**

```
and for removing mutiline comment 

select the statement that you want to uncommented then

use **ctrl+shift+/**
```

> SINGLE LINE COMMENT
>
> For single line comment
>
> use **ctrl+/**

Comment: How does this differ from Hugo Gresse's answer?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> works well for me on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

**In LINUX**

1.**Single line** commenting. Ctrl + /

2.For **block comment** Ctrl + Shift + /

Comment: This seems like a repeat of many of the existing answers, including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25527386).

Comment: I think no one given answer for linux

Answer (score 2):

on mac, using uk english keyboard layout to reach quickcomment in android studio the key combination is:

> cmd  +  alt(option)  +  /

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are using / and not \ ? 
On Mac I have found by default:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comments using // notation

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comments using /* */ notation

Answer (score 2):

Mac (French-Canadian Keyboard):

Line Comment hold both: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>É</kbd>

Block Comment hold all three: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>É</kbd>

"É" is on the same position as "?/" in english one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are used with Eclipse, there is something in Settings>Keymap Keymaps: and you can pick Eclipse to keep the same shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

In android studio you can do 
single comment with (go to line then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>)
and 
block comment with ( select text then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>)

Also if you want to change color of commented text 
go to `File->Settings->IDE settings->Editor->Color & fonts->Java->(Line comment or block comment)` and change properties.
I prefer it to be green which is used in notepad++ editor.

Answer (score 1):

For **Line Comment** hold both:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

For **Block Comment** hold all three:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Same way to remove the comment block.

Answer (score 1):

In the Icelandic MAC keyboard: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Mac:

To comment/uncomment one line, use: Ctrl + /.

To comment/uncomment a block, use: Ctrl + Shift + /.

Answer (score 0):

You can add three slashes.

```
/// Add comments
```

this can clear the "comment out code 2 lines" issues.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that command Ctrl + Shift + / works on Windows only in case if there is no indentation on the left. I.e. if you need to comment out an entire function or class, you must additionally press Enter at the top and bottom of the class/function.
It helped me.