# A keyboard shortcut to comment/uncomment the select text in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

How do I comment out several lines of text selected in the IDE with a control key combination?

I thought that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> was the correct sequence, but that's not working.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25523490/465053).

Answer (score 149, accepted):

To comment/uncomment one line, use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

To comment/uncomment a block, use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: In fact,  `Ctrl + /` can be used to comment/uncomment multiple selected lines using line commenter `//`, while `Ctrl  Shift /` uses block commenter `/*  ...   */`

Answer (score 22):

MAC QWERTY (US- keyboard layout) without numpad:

Line comment : <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> 

Block comment: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

---

MAC QWERTZ (e.g. German keyboard layout):

Android Studio Version ≥ 3.2:

Line comment : <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> 

Block comment: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad /</kbd>

thx @Manuel

---

Android Studio Version ≤ 3.0:

Line comment : <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>-</kbd>

Block comment: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>-</kbd> doesn't work for me with german layout. That is for preassigned code folding.

Comment: What about Mac's with german keyboard without a numpad?

Answer (score 19):

From menu, Code -> Comment with Line Commment. So simple.
[image]

Or, alternatively, add a shortcut as the following:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, usually, you have found the shortcut but it doesn't work because you have not a NumPad.
Actually, the only one issue I found is to set my own shortcut with the one I suppose should works.

First step, find the IDE shortcuts : `cmd + shift + A` enter shortcuts
[image: First step, find the IDE shortcuts : <code>cmd + shift + A</code> enter shortcuts]

Second step : Find Comments Shortcut with the finder
[image]

Third step : Set your custom shortcut (I suggest `cmd + shift + /` or `cmd + :` )
[image]

Now enjoy, it works on a macBook without NumPad

edit : cmd + shift + : has conflicts

Edit : this both works without conflicts
[image]Issue on MacBook

Answer (score 7):

At least in Android Studio 2.2.3 with default key mapping, to comment or uncomment a select text, same hotkeys are used as Toggle. Using the hotkeys changes the state from comment to uncomment, and next time Uncomment to comment on next and vice versa.

**1. Comment / uncomment a block of code**

Comment sample: /* --- Code  block ---- */

Hotkey: **Ctrl + Shift + "/"**

Using the same key combinations again will **"toggle"** commenting or uncommenting the selection.

**2. Comment / uncomment a line of code**

Comment sample: // -- Code ---

Hotkey: **Ctrl + "/"**

Using the same key combinations again will **"toggle"** commenting or uncommenting the selection.

**Note:** Key mapping can be changed to different schemes like eclipse, visual studio... or to the custom hotkeys in File -> Settings -> Keymap

Answer (score 4):

On **Mac** you need **cmd + /** to comment and uncomment.

Comment: On most Scandinavian keyboards, `/` is obtained by pressing Shift-7. However, CMD+SHIFT+7 doesn't work. So I recommend you open up the Keymaps in settings and add it manually. Mine is `CMD+SHIFT+7`.

Comment: I had Swedish keyboard and I had to change Keymap settings

Answer (score 3):

if you are findind keyboard shortcuts for Fix doc comment like this:

```
/**
 * ...
 */
```

you can do it by useing Live Template(setting - editor - Live Templates - add)

```
/**
 * $comment$
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `regions`. See https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/06/21/android-studio-intellij-idea-code-regions/

Select a block of code, then press Code > Surround With... (Ctrl + Alt + T) and select "region...endregion Comments" (2).

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 and Android Studio: Ctrl + / (on small num pad), don't use Ctrl + Shift-7!

Answer (score 0):

Default shortcuts is under **Preferences -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Code** menu

- Add a shortcut for a single line comment (e.g. Ctrl+ ...)
- Add a shortcut for a block comment (e.g. Ctrl+...)

You can use default one or customize it by right click