# The comment /* */ don't work when a string include "*/"

Tags: java, android

The comment of Code 1 works well in Android Studio.

After I insert the chars "*/" to the string s, the comment of Code 2 cause error, how can I fix it? Thanks!

**Code 1**

```
    /*
    String s="";
   */
```

**Code 2**

```
   /*
    String s="*/";
   */
```

Comment: You just need to escape the special characters as far as I can envision. Have you googled about it? Show your efforts. Community members will help if you show what you have done and then ask about what is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility to use a multi-line comment is to change your code to an equivalent code that doesn't include the **`*/`** in the string.
For example:

Splitting `*/` in two strings

```
/*
String s = "*" + "/";
*/
```

Or using a constant

```
public static final String END_COMMENT = "*/";

/*
String s = END_COMMENT;
*/
```

Or writing as unicode chars

```
/*
String s = "\U002A\U002F";    
*/
```

All this solutions are useful if you have many lines to comment.
If you have only one you can use the single line comment as follow:

```
//String s = "*/";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `//` instead:

```
// String s="*/";
```

Comment: Thanks! I need comment a block, the code  String s="*/" is only part of my block, so I have to use /*..*/

Comment: @HelloCW You don't *have* to, you can add `//` to each line. Your IDE probably has an easy shortcut for that (in Eclipse it's `Ctrl + /`).

Comment: Thanks! I use Android studio, but I think add // for each line is too complex

Comment: [Comment select text in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660291/comment-select-text-in-android-studio)

Comment: single line comment only this line. and for rest where this is not the issue, use block comment.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava that doesn't work because the line comment is commented out by the block comment.

Comment: `/*
*somecode
*/
// code with special char
/*
* some code
*/`

Comment: @RamanShrivastava, I see. I can't speak for OP, but I would definitely prefer my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    String s="\*\/";
            */
```

Comment: Thanks! but, will it change the string s if I use \*\/" ?

Comment: This will not compile **without** the comment. `\*` and `\/` are not valid escape sequences.

Comment: yes you are right. I dont know your use case, so I mentioned that you can use escape. Otherwise using // for comment is better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to escape `*/` inside a comment block. But there are a number of ways to avoid explicitly using that sequence in your code, while keeping it functionally the same. For example:

```
String s="*"+"/";
```